# How to use the choice command?

Tags: batch-file

I need the choice command to do the same thing as this block of code:

```
set /p start= Select Mode:
if %start% == 1 goto money
if %start% == 2 goto payouts
if %start% == 3 goto tutorial
if %start% == 4 exit /b
```

I have been trying for quite some time now and cannot figure it out Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `%errorlevel%` variable when using the `CHOICE` command.

Comment: From the HELP file for the `CHOICE` command: **The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the answer by fvu, is to use the `%ErrorLevel%` variable as Squashman suggested:

```bat
Choice /C 1234 /M "Select Mode: "
If %ErrorLevel%==1 GoTo money
If %ErrorLevel%==2 GoTo payouts
If %ErrorLevel%==3 GoTo tutorial
Exit/B
[:money | :payouts | :tutorial]
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is not check the value of `errorlevel` at all, but directly use it in a `goto` command. In this way, you avoid the usual series of `if` commands, so the code is simpler.

```
choice /C 1234 /M "Select Mode: "
goto option-%errorlevel%
```

The rest of the code shoud be like this:

```
:option-1 money
echo Money
goto loop

:option-2 payouts
echo Payouts
goto loop

:option-3 tutorial
echo Tutorial
goto loop

:option-4
exit /B
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the command choice like this

```
choice /c 1234 /M "Select Mode: "
```

upon exit, errorlevel will be set to the **index** (starting with 1) of the selected choice. For acting upon the errorlevel it's important to remember that "if errorlevel n" traps not only n, but also all higher values, meaning that they need to be specified in reverse

```
 if errorlevel 4 goto exit
 if errorlevel 3 goto tutorials
 if errorlevel 2 goto payout
 if errorlevel 1 goto money
```